# How to fully close Opera browser via RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera, selenium-grid

I'm attempting to add Opera to a node on our Selenium Grid but running into a problem closing the Opera browser.  In Opera, closing the last tab in a browser does not close the browser.  It instead launches something called Speed Dial.  This is apparently the default behavior in Opera. I've tried to disable Speed Dial but it doesn't appear to prevent this behavior.

Due to the tests running via RemoteWebDriver, I can't just call a script on the Opera node to close the window.

I've tried the traditional method, which closes the tab but then Opera launches either an empty or speed dial tab:

```
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

I've tried performing an action and sending keys into the html body:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")),Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "W");
action.build().perform();
driver.quit();
```

I've also tried building an action and sending keys into the ether:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SHIFT, "W");
action.build().perform();
driver.quit();
```

Has anyone found a suitable workaround for this 'feature'?

Comment: what os you are using on remote machine?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Windows Server 2016

Comment: hello Nick. did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/44).

So thanks to the Kryshtopenko the solution is:

- For windows:

  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im opera.exe");`
- For macOS:

  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pgrep 'Opera' | xargs kill");`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. My code is in C#

```
Utility.Instance.KillProcess("opera");
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
Utility.Instance.KillProcess("operadriverserver");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Kapil, but I don't think you can kill a process on a remote machine.

Comment: hello Nick. did you fix it?