# selenium unable to close Speed Dial in Opera

Tags: python, selenium

In Opera, I am trying to close all tabs by using **driver.close** but the last tab does not close the browser.

Anyone know how to close the browser completely or disable this Speed Dial?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **driver.quit** instead of driver.close

This will close all instances of browser.

**driver.close**

will only close the instance of browser which WebDriver is currently focusing on.

Comment: I I've tried to use driver.quit but the speed dial tab still here

Comment: the problem is like 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717985/how-to-fully-close-opera-browser-via-remotewebdriver

Comment: In that post he's killing the process. You may go for it ! But for that you should have admin privilege

Answer (score 0):

Use quit() as it is closes all tabs

```
driver.quit();
```